# jquery document with not selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I have some search fields on a page. Upon pressing 'enter' anything in these fields will then get filtered on for a dataset that's displayed on a table.

```
$("document").on('keyup', (e) => {
    if (e.keyCode === 13) {
        searchAndDraw();
    }
});
```

My issue is that I have a `table #myTable`  with some `textareas` in `td`s . Hitting 'enter' inside a textarea also triggers the search as the table is inside the document.

How can I apply this `keyup` event to the doc but exclude `#myTable`?

I tried `$("document:not(#tliId)").on('keyup'...` but that does not work.

Comment: Why don't you give all the search fields a class, and bind the handler to that class?

Comment: It should be `$("document :not(#tliId)")` -- you need a space to match a descendant element.

Comment: well you should not be using an id selector if it is more than one element

Comment: Think you mean something like `$(document).children(":not('#tliOd')").on("keyup", function(){})`. You could also check the ID inside the callback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can target it to use enter on the inputs and exclude textarea

```js
$(document).on('keyup', ":input:not(textarea)", (e) => {
  if (e.key === "Enter") {
    console.log("Enter");
  }
});
```

```css
label {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label></label><input />
<label></label><textarea></textarea>
<label></label><textarea></textarea>
<label></label><input />
```

If you do not want the input to be in focus and they can hit enter anywhere you can check to see what the target is a textarea or not.

```js
$(document).on('keyup', (e) => {
  if (e.key === "Enter" && !$(e.target).is('textarea')) {
    console.log("Enter");
  }
});
```

```css
label {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label></label><input />
<label></label><textarea></textarea>
<label></label><textarea></textarea>
<label></label><input />
```